# shell scripts - "nawk"

Tags: awk, sh, nawk

Hi i ve been trying to read records from a final_customer_total.txt which contains details like size of processed files. I used "nawk" command to read the final_customer_total.txt to calculate total size processed  and then store the total sum into another file .

variable t= size of unprocessed files
for example let

t=1000

**input file :**

file1  100
file2  250
file3  300

**expected output:**

Total size needs to be processed : 1650

**actual output:**

file1  100
file2  250
file3  300
Total size needs to be processed : 1650

my concern content of inupt file also coming in output which i dont want!!
below is the command i tried

```
cat final_customer_total.txt |nawk '{total = total + $1} END{printf ("\nTotal size :"(total + t)/1024/1024/1024" GB")}'t=$t >>customer_total_size.txt
```

when i tried with "awk" its getting errored
**Error :awk bailing out near line 1**

Comment: Consider editing your post to show sample input data and expected output AND your current output and why it is wrong ALONG with any system error messages that are generated. It's too hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish based on above description. Good luck.

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding the value of `$2`? Your reported output also doesn't match what you describe in other respects.

Comment: The `t=$t` should be separated from the program by at least a space.  That would be the source of the syntax error.  Whether you can pass the `var=value` after the program depends on `nawk`; consult its manual page.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you want to be:

```
nawk -v t=$t '
{
    total = total + $1
}
END {
    printf ("Total size needs to be processed: %d GiB\n",(total+t)/1024/1024/1024)
}' final_customer_total.txt > _cts.txt
mv final_customer_total.txt final_customer_total.txt.old
mv _cts.txt final_customer_total.txt
```